# Fedora how to automatically run the ssh daemon

Tags: ssh, fedora

I would like to know what are the ways to automatically start daemons (sshd) in Fedora system. I know I can write a startup script that will put on `/etc/init.d/`.

What are the other options?

Somewhere I read that now in the new version of this can be done using the commands in the terminal, but I do not remember what it was.

EDIT: My 2 question.
I install ssh from source. When keys are generated for a server? During the installation?

Comment: You don't need to compile ssh from source, Fedora already provides a package with ssh (which comes with systemd init file).

Comment: Yes, I know it. But for the purposes of education do everything step by step. I do not know at which point the keys are generated for the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via [`systemctl`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd):

```
systemctl enable sshd.service
```

Comment: Just run it after installing ssh yes? Nothing more?

Comment: @user3193748 Usually it will be set up to run automatically during the installation...I've had instances in which it doesn't before so in that case you can use the command I gave you in the answer.